# Windows Explorer navigate sound

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Whenever you navigate into a folder or click back or forward buttons in Windows Explorer, it plays short "click" sound. I imagine there's a way to turn that off, but haven't been able to find it.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7_3xxQXgFs

"It's like a clickin' noise!"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable all Windows sounds by going to Control Panel > Sounds and Audio Devices > Sounds and using the drop-down, choose No Sounds.  For just Explorer based programs, scroll down to Windows Explorer and find Start Navigation and click that.  Then choose (none).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! On Windows 7, this option in Control Panel is just called "Sounds", or you can type in "change system sounds" in the Start - Run.

Comment: Good to know.  I'm still hanging strong and fully committed to XP 64-bit!